# Error while installing Qiskit 0.44.2: "Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully."

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to install Qiskit 0.44.2 on a mac mini (macOS Sonoma) following instructions given in the page https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html. I am getting the following error at the instruction "pip install qiskit":

```
pip install qiskit
Collecting qiskit
  Obtaining dependency information for qiskit from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/23/51152bd3cfd912b1587dff8c3e3535ab762c336b48898d71bcc1283a1675/qiskit-0.44.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached qiskit-0.44.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.2 kB)
Collecting qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1 (from qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/6c/b561de54eac8af808381a61e124d9a115a1803133d3987048fe8805d4a4c/qiskit_terra-0.25.2.1-cp38-abi3-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached qiskit_terra-0.25.2.1-cp38-abi3-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
Collecting rustworkx>=0.13.0 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for rustworkx>=0.13.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/1e/dacf2027977ce48c1cc9b3f0c449e56c5eb519f8aa4a8bdbf5e20d7e692f/rustworkx-0.13.2-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached rustworkx-0.13.2-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.17 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for numpy>=1.17 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/72/6d1cbdf0d770016bc9485f9ef02e73d5cb4cf3c726f8e120b860a403d307/numpy-1.26.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached numpy-1.26.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (53 kB)
Collecting ply>=3.10 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Using cached ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting psutil>=5 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Using cached psutil-5.9.5-cp38-abi3-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (246 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.5 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for scipy>=1.5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/0e/7e2c614d4c892e7fc9f44f4bf16a4661c7f9112f856c3a14f444e43a6ad4/scipy-1.11.3-cp312-cp312-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached scipy-1.11.3-cp312-cp312-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (217 kB)
Collecting sympy>=1.3 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Using cached sympy-1.12-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 MB)
Collecting dill>=0.3 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for dill>=0.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/3a/74a29b11cf2cdfcd6ba89c0cecd70b37cd1ba7b77978ce611eb7a146a832/dill-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached dill-0.3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.0 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting stevedore>=3.0.0 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Obtaining dependency information for stevedore>=3.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/68/e739fd061b0aba464bef8e8be48428b2aabbfb3f2f8f2f8ca257363ee6b2/stevedore-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached stevedore-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting symengine<0.10,>=0.9 (from qiskit-terra==0.25.2.1->qiskit)
  Using cached symengine-0.9.2.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['cmake', 'symengine'].
      
      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.
      
      If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
      on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
      Instead, consider the following options:
      
      1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
      2. use a `src-layout`
      3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names
      
      To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about installation of Python library, not QC itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue you're hitting is that Qiskit doesn't support Python 3.12 yet. Python 3.12 was only released a few days ago, and it typically takes some time for some libraries to have releases that include support for the new version, especially those with extensions written in compiled languages (C, C++, Rust, etc.). The issue tracking Python 3.12 support for Qiskit is here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/10887 In the short term I'd recommend trying to use an older release of Python, for example Python 3.11 should work perfectly fine.

The actual error you're seeing there is that the Qiskit dependency symengine hasn't released precompiled binaries for Python 3.12 yet, so `pip` is attempting to build the package from source and that is failing. You can try reading the symengine documentation to build it from source, but it's probably just easier to wait or downgrade your Python version.